# Programmatically and temporarily disable SNI check in JAX-RS client with sun.net.**.HttpsClient

Tags: java, jax-ws

I'm getting the old `HTTP transport error: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: handshake alert: unrecognized_name` error on service where I need to disable SNI handshake because reasons. I do NOT want to do it globally with `System.setProperty("jsse.enableSNIExtension", "false");` as suggested elsewhere and the http binding uses `sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient` and I can't seem to change that. I have tried approaches like https://erikwramner.wordpress.com/2013/03/27/trust-self-signed-ssl-certificates-and-skip-host-name-verification-with-jax-ws/

where I have set custom SSLSocketFactories and HostnameVerifiers like so:

```
 BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) webServicePort;
            Map requestContext = bp.getRequestContext();
            requestContext.put("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.https.client.SSLSocketFactory", getTrustingSSLSocketFactory());
            requestContext.put("com.sun.xml.ws.transport.https.client.SSLSocketFactory", getTrustingSSLSocketFactory());
            final NaiveHostnameVerifier naiveHostnameVerifier = new NaiveHostnameVerifier();
            requestContext.put("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.https.client.hostname.verifier", naiveHostnameVerifier);
            requestContext.put("com.sun.xml.ws.transport.https.client.hostname.verifier", naiveHostnameVerifier);
```

This simply has no effect since the http client doesn't seem to honour these properties.

Any tips appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem... activating `java.net.debug` system property to `all` I have determined that the problem is that the server is somehow misconfigured (it accepts negotiating the SNI handshake, but doesn't accept the name we pass for its name ---the one we used to connect to it)  That's frequently a server misconfiguration, as the server responds with `unrecognized_name` for its own name, and this leads to the client dropping the connection (java maintainers assume the server must know the name we use to connect to it).

That's not a problem with `HostnameVerifier` instances anyway, as the client has not already verified the server name (and that is hostname verifier used to), as presented by it in the handshake (indeed, the client aborts the connection after the SERVER HELLO handshake).  The connection is being dropped by the client after the warning (error `112` of the SSL protocol)  So client handshake SHOULD be configured to continue on such event.  By noway the server is dropping the connection and no server hostname verification is being made locally, we only need to make is **to proceed with the initial handshake after the warning message from the server**.  As I have no source code for the `SSLSocketImpl` class at this moment, I'm not able to further investigate the problem, so probably I'll come againt with more information, once I get the source code and test if **there's another means to set that property of the `SSLSocketImpl` instance than to get it from the system property configuration.**

What mainly confuses people is that SNI handshake is used to allow server to use multi domain (or virtual hosts) in the handshake, so it normally is equiped with a properly designed certificate (which is what fails) having alternate dns entries for the client used names.  As the name list is empty or has only the canonical name of the host, the name used by the client is not recognized and that's returned to the client (which should interpret it as a warning), but java's default implementation, depending on system's property, continues or drops the connection.  Another means to configure that on a per connection basis should be enabled, but I don't know it yet.

## EDIT

After looking at openjdk source code (sorrry, but Oracle's implementation doesn't publish code for [`ClientHandshaker`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/sun/security/ssl/ClientHandshaker.java?av=f) class, there's only one place where the internal field `enableSNIextension` (`private`, `final` and `static` field, so no chance to change it once the class has been intialized) is initialized.  This makes the algorithm to behave one way only, once you have loaded the `ClientHandshaker` class.

As the value is only checked to include the optional SNI extension in the initial `helloclient` message, the answer to it is fixed, so the only way to bypass it once it has defaulted to `true` **is to configure a proper certificate on the server including the proper server name in the alternative server names list, or to disable SNI negotiation at all in the server**.  You can have a look at the implementation source for openJDK [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/sun/security/ssl/ClientHandshaker.java?av=f).

## EDIT 2

There's a more involved approach, that allows you to disable SNI extension for just one connection, and implies to use a  `SSLConnectionSocketFactory` derived factory like this:

```
SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf =
    new SSLConnectionSocketFactory( 
          ctx,  // specific context, or default
          SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER  // important, see the text below
    ) {
                @Override
                public Socket connectSocket( int connectTimeout,
                                             Socket socket,
                                             HttpHost host,
                                             InetSocketAddress remoteAddress,
                                             InetSocketAddress localAddress,
                                             HttpContext context )
                    throws IOException {
                    return super.connectSocket( connectTimeout,
                                                socket,
                                                new HttpHost( remoteAddress.getAddress(),
                                                              remoteAddress.getPort() ),
                                                remoteAddress,
                                                localAddress,
                                                context );
                }

            };
CloseableHttpClient cl =
    HttpClients.custom()
               .setSSLSocketFactory( sslsf )
               .build();
```

as you'll see, this uses the plain address to connect to the socket, so no hostname is used to pass to the remote server, disallowing effectivelly the SNI.  It has a drawback, you need to construct it with a match all hostname verifier (as shown above), as it will fail on verifying the server name (this is made just after initial handshake has been finished inside the `SSLConnectionSocketFactory` superclass, and fails as the address used doesn't match the hostname the server uses in it's certificate)